# How to display Notification multiple times based on number of items in the list

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My requirement is to display Banner messages on UI based on no of items in a list.

On _Layout file I was calling my partial view:

```
@Html.Partial("~/_Notification.cshtml")
```

_Notification.cshtml

```
    <div id="outage-notification" class="row" style="display: none;">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div id="notification-content" class="notification-content"></div>
                <div class="dismiss-notification"><a class="small noloader" href="javascript: void(0);" >@CommonUIResources.Dismiss</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/outageNotification")
```

My javascript file:

```
var outageNotification;
class OutageNotification {
    constructor() {
        this.setup();
    }
    setup() {
        var date1 = new Date().toUTCString();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Notification/GetBannerNotifications",
            data: { dateTime: date1 },
            success: function (notificationMessage) {
                if (notificationMessage !== undefined && notificationMessage !== "") {
                    $("#notification-content").append(notificationMessage);
                    $("#notification").fadeIn("slow");
                }
                else {
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
$(document).ready(() => {
    this.outageNotification = new OutageNotification();
});
```

My Controller method:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Notification/GetBannerNotifications")]
        public JsonResult GetBannerNotifications(DateTime? dateTime)
        {
            var listOfStrings = this.notificationService.GetBannerNotifications(dateTime.Value);
            return this.Json(listOfStrings, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Output:
[image]

The below image contains only one string, but if I multiple strings then also its showing all the strings in one image.

It's displaying all the strings into a single string and displays that string in UI.
But I need to display this image multiple times depends on a number of strings in the List.

Answer (score 0):

> It's displaying all the strings into a single string and displays that string in UI.
> But I need to display this image multiple times depends on a number of strings in the List.

If the `GetBannerNotifications` action method returns a list of string, you would get a json array from the returned data on JS client side, like below.

```
["ohello1 1/14/2021 12:00:00 PM-1/14/2021 12:30:00 PM","ohello2 1/15/2021 12:00:00 PM-1/15/2021 12:30:00 PM"]
```

To achieve your above requirement, you can try to iterate over the returned json array data, then dynamically show your `outage-notification` widget.

```
var date1 = new Date().toUTCString();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Notification/GetBannerNotifications",
    data: { dateTime: date1 },
    success: function (notificationMessage) {
        if (notificationMessage !== undefined && notificationMessage !== "") {

            console.log(notificationMessage);

            $("#notification-content").html(notificationMessage[0]);

            $.each(notificationMessage, function (i, mes) {
                if (i > 0) {
                    console.log(mes);

                    //code logic here depends on which plugin you are using

                    //follwoing code snippet for testing purpose with using fadeIn&fadeOut animation
                    $("#outage-notification").fadeIn(5000, function () {
                        $("#outage-notification").fadeOut("slow");

                        $("#notification-content").html(mes);
                    });
                }                        

            })

        }
        else {
        }
    }
});
```